# operator<< overloading "error: passing 'const...."

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
ofstream& operator<<(ostream &outStream, const EventClass &eventObject)
{
  outStream << eventObject.getEventName() << " event at "
    << eventObject.getEventTime() << endl;

  return(outStream);
}
```

I believe this snippet is sufficient to analyze the error.

When I compile my code I get the following errors:

> error: passing ‘const EventClass’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string EventClass::getEventName()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>   
>     outStream << eventObject.getEventName() << " event at "
>
> error: passing ‘const EventClass’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int EventClass::getEventTime()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>   
>       << eventObject.getEventTime() << endl;
>
> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream&}’ from expression of type ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’
>   
>     return(outStream);

Any ideas how to solve these errors?

Comment: Is the `getEventName` method marked as `const`?

Comment: No, it is not. Does it have to be const to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it has to be const to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks that worked. What about the last error? it doesn't like my return statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure `getEventName` and `getEventTime` are declared as `const`, as follows:

```
std::string getEventName() const;
int getEventTime() const;
```

in the declaration and implementation of `EventClass`. This tells the compiler that these methods will not modify the fields of the object in any way.

Also, the last line of the operator should simply be: `return outStream;`

Edit: also `std::ofstream` is not the same as `std::ostream`. Generally, for `operator<<`, it needs to be defined as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const EventClass& eventObject) { 
    //blah 
}
```

to encompass *any* stream type.

Comment: You should also point out that `ostream` and `ofstream` are not the same, for the last error.

Answer (score 1):

`eventObject` is a reference to a `const` object, so its `getEventName()` and `getEventTime()` methods need to be declared as `const` as well, to specify that they don't modify the object they are called on, eg:

```
std::string getEventName() const;
int getEventName() const;
```

Also, your operator is declared as returning an `ofstream`, but it needs to return an `ostream` instead, to match the input:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &outStream, const EventClass &eventObject)
```